# logging in to AWS using Login and Password using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am having an application designed in Java where I am willing to log in using Username and Password for AWS. I know the way to use default security credentials defined [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html) but it is not valid for my application requirements. Is there any way I could use a username and password to log in to my AWS account using Java API?

Comment: what are your application requirements?

Comment: I need a user to temporary log in to my application. I need some S3 bucket metadata from their S3 buckets with their permission for further processing. @yali

Comment: Your application would ideally assume a minimally-permissioned, cross-account IAM role that the other account owner provides for you. IAM username + password is not usable in API requests (you need AWS credentials associated with an IAM user or an IAM role, preferably the latter).

Comment: @jarmod could you please guide me to some documentation or implementation example? Thanks

Comment: See [IAM tutorial: Delegate access across AWS accounts using IAM roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Based on your application requirements**

You need to create temporary security credentials by AWS Security Token Service (AWS STS) and make the expiration for them

Here are some resources that can help

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html

and here for [Getting Temporary Credentials with AWS STS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/prog-services-sts.html)

Comment: this fetches the credentials from aws credentials file